# How do I remove domain admin control from windows that don't use AD

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, group-policy, windows-domain

I have a computer running Windows 10 that has a Domain Admin block on the local admin which has blocked me from installing any update that is the anniversary update or later.

I did also try to make a guest user for a party so they could use Spotify and VLC, but that was also blocked by the domain admin.

I can't find any way to remove it because the computer is not in a domain or has a local domain admin.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you remove the pc from the domain using the local admin account? That should remove all domain policies. If the lock is specific to a certain local admin account, you could promote another user to admin; if your local admin account is blocked from doing that too, you shoud use an [offline registry editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd).

Comment: Nop. It whas like that when i got it

Comment: Then start with removing the pc from the domain (`WIN+PAUSE` `->` `Advanced system settings` `->` `Computer name` `->` `Change...`). That will hopefully enable you to remove any domain policy restrictions.

Comment: I will try it but it will probebly not work. I think that it is a bit obvious that you would do that to remove it,

Comment: Just "reset" Windows 10, it's probably your shortest path to a working system.  That should have been done before it was given to you.

Comment: How did you receive this computer? Was it given to you? Purchased? Etc? Optimally, the previous owners should have wiped it prior to giving it to you, as @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 notes.

Comment: "the computer is not in a domain".. I suspect that it is.. even if you can not connect to said domain.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 you can easily Reset a computer.

First, backup any data you need to keep.

Next, open **Settings**, go to **Update and Recovery**, and then **Recovery**.

*Note, your options may have different names depending on the version of Windows 10 you're currently running.*

There should be options to reset the computer. You'll want to use the most thorough reset option to fully remove any and all previous controls and settings.

*Here's the Microsoft Support site detailing how to use the various recovery options: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options*